# Do audit revision take longer to load than actual revisions?

Tags: bug, review-audits

I've been doing some revisions recently (in the first posts queue) and noticed that audits take a bit longer to load than actual posts.

Perhaps it was only an unfortunate coincidence, but when I was presented with my last audit **I knew it was an audit, even before I read it**. The load time of the previous audit also was  abnormal (only a few seconds, but quite different from actual posts that load immediatly after one clicks one of the buttons).

I understand that audits are intentionally easy, but they should not come yelling "hey, I am an audit".

Comment: Yet to see an audit on SharePoint exchange. Anyway, if what you say is correct, I fear someone will find a way to capitalize on said latency.

Comment: Yeah, I've witnessed this behaviour sometimes. Not always though. Sometimes the normal reviews take time to load as well though.